# SQL join into a Recursive CTE with parameters

Tags: sql-server, database, common-table-expression

I am trying to use an SQL Query to create some client side reporting for my company. There exists 3 tables that I would like to join together. One of the tables may require a CTE as I need to recursively go through a table and return a row. Here is how the tables are structured (simply).

I want a output table that, for each WorkOrder, displays the most recently completed task in DataCollection (including its time) and the next Op in the TaskListing. I figured a CTE maybe is the only way to recursively go through each row and determine what task is next. (By checking if the completed Op exists in PreOp column). If the completed cell doesn't exist as a preOp it should default to the MAX(Op) (the last task).

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WorkOrder](
  [WorkOrderID][int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [Column1] [nvarchar](20),
  [Column2] [nvarchar](20)
  )

INSERT INTO WorkOrder VALUES(1,'x','y');
INSERT INTO WorkOrder VALUES(2,'x','y');
INSERT INTO WorkOrder VALUES(3,'x2','y2');

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataCollection](
  [DataCollection][int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [WorkOrderID][int] NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES WorkOrder(WorkOrderID),
  [CellTask] [nvarchar](20),
  [TimeCompleted] [DateTime]
  )

 INSERT INTO DataCollection VALUES(1,1,'cella','2016-08-09 00:00:00');
 INSERT INTO DataCollection VALUES(2,1,'cellb','2016-08-10 00:00:00');
 INSERT INTO DataCollection VALUES(3,1,'cellc','2016-08-11 00:00:00');
 INSERT INTO DataCollection VALUES(4,2,'cella','2016-08-09 00:00:00');
 INSERT INTO DataCollection VALUES(5,2,'cellb','2016-08-10 00:00:00');

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TaskListing](
  [TaskListingID][int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [WorkOrderID][int] NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES WorkOrder(WorkOrderID),
  [Op][nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
  [preOP][nvarchar](20),
  [CellTask][nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
  [Completed][bit] NOT NULL
  )

 INSERT INTO TaskListing VALUES(1,1,'10',NULL,'cella',0);
 INSERT INTO TaskListing VALUES(2,1,'20','10','cellb',0);
 INSERT INTO TaskListing VALUES(3,1,'30',NULL,'cellc',1);
 INSERT INTO TaskListing VALUES(4,1,'40','10,30','celld',0);
 INSERT INTO TaskListing VALUES(5,2,'10',NULL,'cella',1);
 INSERT INTO TaskListing VALUES(6,2,'20','10','cellb',1);
 INSERT INTO TaskListing VALUES(7,2,'30','20','cellc',0);
```

The Output table will represent, for each WorkOrder, the most recently completed cell (from the DataCollection Table, TimeCompleted column) & The next cell in the Work Flow (by looking at the rows on the TaskListing Table for the given WorkOrderID and looking for a row that contain the completed task as a 'PreOp'). If it can't find the completed task as a preOp for any other row it should default to the last task.

The part of the Query I'm having most trouble with is filling in the NextTaskCell column. I need to write a query that looks at all the tasks for a given WorkOrderID (In the TaskListing Table) and based on the completed task, determine what is the next task. I'm finding it difficult to feed in both a WorkOrderID & CellTask then find an instance of itself in the PreOp column.

Output Table

```
+-------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+
| WorkOrderId | LastCompletedCell |     CompletedOn     | NextTaskCell |
|(WorkOrder)  | (DataCollection)  | (DataCollection)    |(TaskListing) |
+-------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+
|           1 | cellc             | 2016-08-11 00:00:00 | celld        |
|           2 | cellb             | 2016-08-10 00:00:00 | cellc        |
+-------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+
```

I thank you in advance for your time. If there is any other questions please let me know and I'll try to answer them.

Link to SQL Fiddle [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/99c65)

Comment: To help us help you better, please review the following: [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/). Make sure you clearly describe what you want the results to be (i.e. expected output), what the results are of your query so we can see where things go wrong. As your question is now, it's rather unclear what your issue is. You should also probably consider trimming down the question a bit.

Comment: I've trimmed and edited the question based on your suggestions. I hope this makes it easier to understand. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Describe please (in human terms) how you get the following in expected results. For `WorkOrder=2` you have `LastCompletedCell=cellb` and `NextTaskCell=cellc`. What data leads you to conclude those results? Also, don't focus on the technicals that you think should be used to solve the problem (aka [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). Focus on making it crystal clear how you get from the sample data to the expected output.

Comment: I've updated the post to explain it more clearly. For your case it gets the LastCompleted cell from the DataCollection table (most recent CompletedOn for that workOrder). It gets the value for NextTaskCell by looking at the WorkOrderId to get the rows of the tasks for that Work Order in TaskListing. Within those rows it gets the OP# of the completed task and determines if that OP# is contained in the PreOp field for the other rows. If it exists in another row it should return that rows CellTask. This is not tables of my design so I understand if it seems silly, but I have to work with it.

Comment: Let me know if I have not explained myself properly. I will attempt to further explain the issue and the goal. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query gives you the expected output you have in your question. You should test this query against a larger dataset to make sure it is correct in all cases.

```
;WITH 
    mtc AS ( -- most recent completion date/time for a work order
        SELECT
            dc.WorkOrderID,
            TimeCompleted=MAX(dc.TimeCompleted)
        FROM
            DataCollection AS dc
        GROUP BY
            dc.WorkOrderID
    ),
    lop AS ( -- last operation for work order
        SELECT
            tl.WorkOrderID,
            LastOp=MAX(CAST(tl.Op AS INT))
        FROM
            TaskListing AS tl
        GROUP BY
            tl.WorkOrderID
    )
SELECT
    mtc.WorkOrderID,
    LastCompletedCell=dc.CellTask,
    CompletedOn=dc.TimeCompleted,
    NextTaskCell=ISNULL(tl_next.CellTask,tl_last.CellTask)
FROM
    mtc
    INNER JOIN DataCollection AS dc ON  -- the last completed CellTask
        dc.WorkOrderID=mtc.WorkOrderID AND
        dc.TimeCompleted=mtc.TimeCompleted
    INNER JOIN TaskListing AS tl ON     -- Op for CellTask 
        tl.WorkOrderID=mtc.WorkOrderID AND
        tl.CellTask=dc.CellTask
    INNER JOIN lop ON
        lop.WorkOrderID=mtc.WorkOrderID
    INNER JOIN TaskListing AS tl_last ON -- CellTask for last Op
        tl_last.WorkOrderID=mtc.WorkOrderID AND
        tl_last.Op=lop.LastOp
    LEFT JOIN TaskListing AS tl_next ON -- Look for next CellTask where Op is a PreOp of another CellTask
        tl_next.WorkOrderID=mtc.WorkOrderID AND
        ','+tl_next.preOP+',' LIKE '%,'+tl.Op+',%'
ORDER BY
    mtc.WorkOrderId;
```

---

Note: It is a bad idea to store `PreOps` as a comma-separated string. This is not how you should store data in relational databases. When you do, you will have to resort to more complex and less efficient queries. To wit, see the join condition in `tl_next`.

Instead you should have a table to store `PreOps` as separate rows, linking to the parent `Op` that depends on it.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm going to implement this into the larger dataset and verify this works. I understand your concern about the preOps column. This isn't a database of my design so I totally understand the frustration. For now I have to work around the prior design.